# How to find a startup project from add-in in VS 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, add-in

I wrote a add-in for VS2012.
At some point I need to find a Project object corresponding to startup project of the solution.
I used  array  _applicationObject.Solution.SolutionBuild.StartupProjects which gives me the name(s) of startup projects then I go to  _applicationObject.Solution.Item ( projectName) which normally returns a "good" Project object.
(my solution is similar to one recommended by Microsoft http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228782.aspx)

But in case when startup project is not on the top level of solution (say there is a solution Sol1, and under it a folder "Demo", and startup project inside "Demo" ) my method doesn't work.

_applicationObject.Solution.SolutionBuild.StartupProjects returns correct name, but collection of projects doesn't contain my startup project - it contains only "Demo" (top level) name.

I hope somebody can show me a correct way to find a startup project

Answer (score 0):

To convert from a startup object name (personally I use full name) to a Project, you need to recursively traverse project hierarchy like this:

```
// REQUIRE(services->dte->Solution != nullptr);
std::vector<gcroot<EnvDTE::Project^>> VSServices::get_all_projects() const
{
REQUIRE(services->dte->Solution != nullptr);
std::vector<gcroot<EnvDTE::Project^>> result;
if (services->dte->Solution->Projects != nullptr)
{
    for each(EnvDTE::Project^ project in services->dte->Solution->Projects)
        get_all_projects_from_project(project, result);
}
return result;
}

void VSServices::get_all_projects_from_project(EnvDTE::Project^ project, 
                                           std::vector<gcroot<EnvDTE::Project^>>& result) const
{
if (project != nullptr)
{
    result.push_back(project);
    if (project->ProjectItems != nullptr)
    {
        for each(EnvDTE::ProjectItem^ item in project->ProjectItems)
        {
            if (item != nullptr)
                get_all_projects_from_project(dynamic_cast<EnvDTE::Project^>(item->Object), result);
        }
    }
}
}
```